# how to refresh adapter view from activity without using events in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, refresh

I'm making an app to debate, every time a user creates a debate, they must set the date and time the debate ends, I also have a recyclerview with a cardview where the list of each debate is shown. Now, through a thread ( multithread) defined in the mainActivity I calculate the current date and time every 1 minute (this does not affect the performance of the app) and I compare it to see if the time and date are greater than the date established as the date and time of the end of the debates If so, the discussion in question should be removed from the recyclerview's discussion list. So far everything works relatively well, the problem is that in order to update the recyclerview I have to change the fragment view and then return to the recycler to see the updated discussion list (with finished discussions removed from the recyclerview). My question is how to update the discussion list in the recyclerview without having to use any event (for example on click or others) or without the need to change views. The idea is that, for example, if a user is in the recycler view and the closing time of a debate passes, then the debate should disappear even if the user is just in the recycler view without doing anything.

code:

activityMain:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    
    public String date_now;
    List<ListDebates> list;
    public ListAdapter listDebates;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new getTime().start();
       
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }

        return true;
    }

    class getTime extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ConexionSQliteHelper conn=new ConexionSQliteHelper(getApplicationContext(),"db_testwuad_7",null,31);
            try {
                while(true){
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            DateTimeFormatter datetime_formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm dd/MM/YYYY");
                            LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
                            date_now = datetime_formatter.format(now);
                            Log.i("hour",date_now);
                            conn.deleteDebate(date_now);
                            list = conn.getDataofDebate();
                            listDebates = new ListAdapter(list, getApplicationContext());
                            listDebates.notifyDataSetChanged();


                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(60000);
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

adapter.class

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {
    private List<ListDebates> data;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    private View.OnClickListener listener;
    public String date_now,name_sent;
    TextView viewer;
    public ListAdapter(List <ListDebates> itemList,Context context){
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = itemList;
        this.context = context;
    }
    //onCreateViewHolder enlaza el adaptador con el archivo xml
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview,null);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }
    //onBindViewHolder establece la comunicación entre el adaptador y la clase ViewHolder
    // .Aquí se envía la información que se quiere mostrar,para ello se ocupa el objeto holder
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
       holder.title.setText(data.get(position).getTitle_debate());
       holder.user.setText(data.get(position).getName_user());
       holder.arguments.setText(data.get(position).getArguments_debate());
       //holder.image_post.s.getImage_debate()));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
    public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener){
        this.listener=listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(listener!=null){
            listener.onClick(v);
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView image_post;
        TextView title,user,arguments;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image_post = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_debate);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            user = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameUserofPost);
            arguments = itemView.findViewById(R.id.arguments_post);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `notifyItem*` apis to add, change/update & remove the dataset in the recyclerview's adapter.

Comment: is that only to work with apis, or is it also useful to use it with data from a relational database?